# How to get data from controller to view?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I need to pass data from controller to view. I used loop in controller which run more than 1 minute.

```
for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++){

$peicedata = getdata();
$ar=explode(",",$peicedata);

$data['firstname']=$ar[0];
$data['lastname']=$ar[1];
$data['email']=$ar[2];
$data['website']=$ar[3];


}
```

above function `getdata()` take around 10 second to get data back. when data get from `getdata()` i want to pass that data immidiate to view.

Comment: @RageZ I want that $data['firstname'] value in view in every loop

Comment: I think reading this: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html would not do you any bad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you use CodeIgniter. You can pass data to template like this:

```
$this->load->view('show', $data);
```

`show` is the template. And please read [User Guide](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html) for more details.

BTW, if your script runs too slow, you should check your code.

Answer (score 1):

Are you passing the data to a view?

`$this->load->view('view', $data);`

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html